# How to make object ignore a light in THREE.JS

Tags: three.js

If you consider a snapshot of my scene:

[image: snapshot of scene]

As you can see I have a plane which acts as the surface which is lit by a `THREE.SpotLight` from above on the Y axis.

What I would like to achieve, is to have a further plane in the dark area which would have a texture mapped to it like a starfield or galaxy or whatever.

I could possibly add another light just for that plane, but I would like to know if i can add a plane and set some properties so that its always fully lit as if the light has no influence, is this even possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use `MeshBasicMaterial` which is not affected by lights.